# Using $where with an asynchronous function in mongo

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I would like to write a query similar to this one

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/function/

```
db.players.find( { $where: function() {
   return (hex_md5(this.name) == "15b0a220baa16331e8d80e15367677ad")
} } );
```

but, in my case, the function that should be called by $where is asynchronous, for example

```
db.players.find( { $where: function(callback) {
   return myAsyncFunction(this.name, callback)
} } );
```

Is this possible to do it with mongo? I did not find any reference in the docs or on google.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$where can only invoke functions that are defined on the server. It won't invoke functions that you defined in your application. It sounds like you are overlooking this aspect.

To answer your stated question, https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/function/ already describes how parameters work so you'll need to define the functions using that convention.